# Como puedo conseguir el nombre de una base de datos, que se forme con la combinación de dos variables?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy comenzando a programar en python (tkinter). Mi problema es el siguiente: Estoy desarrollando una aplicación (la cual  funciona correctamente), sin embargo, necesito que el nombre de la base que genero se forme de la siguiente manera: base_mastografos_conasa_entidad_fechacorte, donde entidad y fechacorte son variables declaradas; anexo un extracto de mi código. Alguien me puede ayudar?. Gracias.

```
def abrir_ventana_mastografos():
# Creamos ventana principal
ventanap=tk.Toplevel()
ventanap.resizable(False, False)#para que no se expanda la ventana
ventanap.title("STCONASA/Aplicación CRUD")
ventanap.geometry("1050x750+450+100")#largoxancho, corod sistema
ventanap.config(bg='#B38E5D')##7FFFD4
log_conasa=PhotoImage(file="conasa_icono.png")
ventanap.iconphoto(False,log_conasa)
ventanas=LabelFrame(ventanap,text="Formulario de mastógrafos",bg='#FFEBCD',font =( 
'Verdana', 15),fg='#56242A')#beig,#621132
ventanas.pack(fill="both",expand="yes",padx=20,pady=29)
ventanap.grab_set()# ventanap bg='#FFEBCD'

#Declaramos nuestras variables

var_id=StringVar()
var_entidad=StringVar()
var_mastografo=StringVar()
var_ubicacion=StringVar()
var_institucion=StringVar()
var_LSMast=StringVar()#cambio a Licencia sanitaria
var_nolicencia=StringVar()
var_tipo=StringVar()
var_funciona=StringVar()
var_adjudicacion=StringVar()
var_afabricacion=StringVar()
var_permisorof=StringVar()
var_nopermisorof=StringVar()
var_produc2021=StringVar()
var_fechacorte=StringVar()
var_nolicencia=StringVar()

def conexionBBDD():
    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("base_mastografos_conasa.db")
    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()

    try:
        miCursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE mastografos (
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        ENTIDAD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        NO_EQUIPO VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        NOM_ESTABLECIMIENTO VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        INSTITUCION VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
        LS_MASTOGRAFO VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        NO_LICENCIA VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,           
        TIPO VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        FUNCIONA VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
        ADJUDICACION VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
        AÑO_FABRICACION INT NOT NULL,
        PERMISO_ROF VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        NO_PERMISO_ROF VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        PRODUCTIVIDAD_2021 INT(10) NOT NULL,
        FECHA_CORTE INT(15) NOT NULL)
        ''')
        messagebox.showinfo("CONEXION","Base de Datos Creada exitosamente")
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("CONEXION", "Conexión exitosa con la base de datos")
```

Comment: Hola amigo, disculpa no entiendo bien tu pregunta tú quieres que dentro del string donde declaras el nombre de la base de datos vayan dos variables con los respectivos datos faltantes ?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Juan Sebastián, disculpas por mi mala redacción, en efecto, busco conseguir el nombre de mi base tal como lo describes. Es decir, creo y conecto con mi base de la siguiente manera:

```
def conexionBBDD():
    miConexion=sqlite3.connect("base_mastografos_conasa.db")
    miCursor=miConexion.cursor()
```

donde actualmente base_mastografos_conasa.db es el nombre de mi base. Existe alguna forma de lograr que este nombre sea como sigue?: base_mastografos_conasa+var_entidad+var_fechacorte.db. Aquí recalco nuevamente, var_entidad=StringVar() y var_fechacorte=StringVar() son dos de mis variables.